# What to do when GSC and Mobile-Friendly test don't agree?

Tags: google-search-console

A few days ago, Google Search Console started reporting some pages as not mobile-friendly, with three different issues:

- Content wider than screen
- Text too small to read
- Clickable elements too close together

At first, I could reproduce them in the Mobile Friendly test that GSC links to (Test Live Page). I was able to fix the issue (a broken Flex container) and the Mobile-Friendly test is now telling me "Page is usable on mobile" for all my pages.

However, Google Search Console is still reporting all the issues and still adding new pages with the issue. But if I click "Test Live Page", it reports as usable on mobile. So I don't know what to do.

I have cleared my WP Rocket cache and my Cloudflare cache.

What could I do to either see the errors somewhere (so that I can fix them) or make sure that GSC sees my fix? My understanding is that GSC and the Mobile-Friendly test should be reporting the same errors.